# Connecting to GMAIL through IMAP using OAuth and the Google account token provided by Android's AccountManager

Tags: android, gmail, imap, token, accountmanager

I want to access GMAIL through IMAP from android, using OAuth. As shown here:
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#imap

I tried to use the auth token returned by the AccountManager as the AUTHENTICATE parameter, and I was not able to authenticate.

I am using this code to get the token:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "android", null, (Activity)this, null, null); 
Bundle authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
String authToken = authTokenBundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
```

And after the IMAP connection, I execute this command:

```
"AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH " + authToken
```

And I receive a invalid argument response.

What am I doing wrong? Is there really a relation between the OAuth token and the Account token? If there is not, how I could get the XOAUTH token from the account token.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use javamail for imap connection? How do you send the auth token to gmail via imap?

Comment: Where you able to get a connection to gmail IMAP service? If so, how did you manage to do so? I am trying to get a connection to SMTP, and I can't seem to get it to work using "mail" as authtoken. The token returned seems to be too short comparing to the examples on http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#smtp.

Comment: Can you post your code that uses the Oauth Token to connect to Gmail via IMAP? I have the Token, but I am unsure how to use it to connect to Gmail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you should be using "android" rather than "mail" when supplying the `authTokenType` in `getAuthToken()`? Alternately you can use "ah" which isn't listed but appears to be asking for access to everything.

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#clientlogin

You also might want to try http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ as it supports the android AccountManager authentication type.

Comment: did it work? is it really possible to use the accountManager token in order to read messages (and other stuff) from gmail? they are saying there that there is no gmail data API , so i don't understand what's going on . how come the most popular service cannot be used?